# dynamic find using multiple NOT LIKE

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to do a complex find in CakePHP that has multiple NOT LIKE variables pulled from a table.

Just as an example of trying to use an array, something like:

```
$blocked_words = array();
array_push($blocked_words,'%apple%','%orange%','%strawberry%','%grapes%');

'NOT' => array(
array('Api.reason LIKE' => $blocked_words)),
```

does not work, only:

```
'NOT' => array(
array('Api.reason LIKE' => '%apple%'),
array('Api.reason LIKE' => '%orange%'),
array('Api.reason LIKE' => '%grapes%')),
```

seems to work. While this is great, it doesn't solve my need when i'm pulling an unknown number of variables. Is there a way to have LIKE work with an array or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it:

```
$blocked_words = array('%apple%','%orange%','%strawberry%','%grapes%');
$conditions = array(); // conditions
foreach ($blocked_words as $word) {
   $conditions['NOT'][] = array('Api.reason LIKE' => "%$word%");
}
```